# Why `v=bf13ba33f40c` this extra query string is passed in the wordpress site url?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress project. I simply installed the wordpress 4.6.1 and completed my project. But there is a problem with the url. It seems to be like `http://example.com/demo/?v=bf13ba33f40c`, I didn't get why `?v=bf13ba33f40c` part is added to url automatically. I set the permalink but it shows no effect. Anybody please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any plug-ins activated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the "geolocalize users with cache support" setting in WooCommerce. If you turn that off the extra get parameter will go away